# Separate huge Hash file into one file based on content (shell scripting)

Tags: linux, bash, shell, hash, awk

I have a huge file of hashes that is displayed like this:

```
username:values:values:password hash:::

username:values:values:password hash:::

username:values:values:password hash:::
```

and so on....

I need to take the hashes with this format for username and put them into another file.

the username needs to start with a letter followed by 6 digits.

```
Examples of usernames i want to put into a new file: 
Y783071:SDF87DSFQ1:DSF98D3EF:DSF98SDF98
G678876:SD8F7SD8F7:DF98SDF89:SDF98S
J110998:SDF98FJ98W:9J493H0L8:3498RJHT
```

However there are a ton of other usernames in this hash file that I do not want that may look like this:
SDFSNPOSAB:9786:sdfb787
EMEU6798:JHB98fds:

etc etc

Preferably in bash or C++.

I was told I should use grep or sed

I'm on a ubuntu linux machine.

Comment: Or it could be done in PHP, or Perl, or Python, or Ruby, or any other language that is now installed on the machine, using `#!shebang` to specify which one it is.  In **this** case, however, good ol' `egrep` might do very nicely.  For instance, the regex `^A` means, "starts with the letter `A`" ...

Comment: Also, if you should be looking for multiple occurrences of the same value, a very handy thing to do is to `sort` (a copy of ...) the file by that key.  Then, you know that all occurrences of each key will be adjacent.

Comment: Right! I wasn't saying that it couldn't be done in other languages, just these are the two I've been working with. Thanks for the response

Comment: *Yep!* Gotcha.  Happy to have (tried to) help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below sed command:

```
sed -n '/^[a-zA-Z]\{1\}[0-9]\{6\}:/p' hash_file > output_file
```

This sed command looks for lines starting with 1 alphabet ( `[a-zA-Z]\{1\}` ) followed by 6 numbers ( `[0-9]\{6\}`) followed by `:`.

Comment: beautiful. exactly what i was looking for, thank you

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, plz accept that as accepted answer.

Comment: if i wanted to pull out lets say a random 500, what would i need to add?

Comment: Sorry i dont understand your requirement.. Please explain

Comment: Well I have somewhere around 15000 usernames, your command successfully stored all of the usernames I was looking for, but what if I want to just store 500 instead of all of them

Comment: You can pipe output of above `sed` to `head -500` and then redirect to get first 500 lines

Comment: thank you! how do i accept your answer as the correct one?

Comment: There will be tick mark on the left of the answer below up-down arrows.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for

```
cat input
username:a dfasdfasdf
username:b
username:c dasfjkl;asd
username:a dfasdfl;j
```

**Code:**

```
awk -F " " '{print > "files_"$1}' input

-> Space separated file is read, redirect to new files based on the first column
```

**Output**

```
ls
files_username:a
files_username:b
files_username:c
```

**Content**

```
more files_*
::::::::::::::
files_username:a
::::::::::::::
username:a dfasdfasdf
username:a dfasdfl;j
::::::::::::::
files_username:b
::::::::::::::
username:b
::::::::::::::
files_username:c
::::::::::::::
username:c dasfjkl;asd
```

Comment: Yeah, I am a *big* fan of `awk` and "it just might be what the doctor ordered" in this case or in cases like this one.  The OP should *definitely* take a close look at what this tool can do. (In fact, the Perl programming language evolved from "a souped-up awk.")  And it doesn't have to be a "one-liner."

Comment: I updated the description to be more specific. Ill look into awk